# button removes previous output

Tags: php, html

ok, I decided to try to search this before I asked this question, but no luck.

How can I keep output from getting removed when I click on a different button? It will only display output of one or the other. Where it displays the output is correct (underneath the button) I think whats causing this is when I click the second button it goes back to its original location (where the first output is) and I think that is why I can't display both outputs at the same time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="">

<p>
<input type="submit" value="Get Uptime" name="uptimebutton" >
<?php

if(isset($_POST['uptimebutton']))
{

        //echo shell_exec('uptime');
        $uptime = shell_exec('uptime');
        echo "<pre>$uptime</pre>";                                                                


}
?></p>

<p><input type="submit" value="GRAB HDD INFO" name="memorybutton" >
<?php
if(isset($_POST['memorybutton']))
{
        $output = shell_exec('df -h');
        echo "<pre>$output</pre>";                                                 
}
?></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One way could be to store the result in a hidden variable <input type=hidden>. then you should be able to extract the other value as well that was determined last time. Just an idea....

Comment: I tried that, but how would I do that using <pre> though? if I don't use <pre> on my output (mostly memorybutton) it will look all weird. I tried input type=hidden but I never got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can store them in session, or any other globally available variables. Something like this might help if you already have started a session:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Get Uptime" name="uptimebutton"/>
                <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['uptimebutton']))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['uptime'] = shell_exec('uptime');
                    }
                    echo "<pre>" . (isset($_SESSION['uptime']) ? $_SESSION['uptime'] : "") . "</pre>";
                ?>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="GRAB HDD INFO" name="memorybutton"/>
                <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['memorybutton']))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['output'] = shell_exec('df -h');
                    }
                    echo "<pre>" . (isset($_SESSION['output']) ? $_SESSION['output'] : "") . "</pre>";
                ?>
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that was just more code that does same thing it did before :(

Comment: @andyADD Maybe I didn't understand your question completely. Do you want to have a log-like history in each field, or the latest for each field?

Comment: When using sessions don't forget session_start() before any output has been sent to the browser.

Comment: What you need is session. But as @Chris mentioned, dont forget to initialize you sessions, and store active session ids somewhere. it's better to use a framework like symphony to handle sessions for you. take your time with sessions in php. Here is the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php . Its counter part in browser side is cookie.